# Route-planning for a graph with nodes and a max "jump" distance between nodes

Tags: algorithm, routes

I have ~6500 nodes with (x,y,z)-coordinates. For my task, I need to find a route from `Node A` to `Node B`, given that I can only move `K` distance between nodes. `K` changes between routes (so it's constant while calculating a given route, but for a new start and end node it may be different).

I imagined doing an A* algorithm, but that would mean that I would have to calculate the distance between each "current" node and all other nodes for each jump, which is unfeasable. I could also pre-compute the graph for each increment of `K` (1, 2, 3, 4) but that would leave me a massive amount of data (maximum `K` would be around 15).

Is there a smart way that, with some precomputation, allows me to quickly lookup such a route. The data set is expected to grow slightly, but would probably never exceed 10.000.

Comment: This post seems useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371187/find-all-coordinates-within-a-circle-in-geographic-data-in-python. I don't quite understand the `k-d tree` (still reading about it), but if it gives you a reasonable time complexity for finding neighbors (given a jump distance) then you could do this in reasonable time. This makes a simple Dijkstra's feasible. 10000 input points also doesn't seem too bad, but I don't have the napkin math to estimate the size of storing such a graph in memory.

Comment: Do you need the shortest route? If not, the unique path in a minimum spanning tree has the property of minimizing the maximum jump distance.

Comment: I am afraid it is the shortest route I am looking for. Otherwise not a bad suggestion.

Comment: Is `K` an upper bound? You could store the neighbors at distance at most 15 in order of increasing distance.

Comment: I may end up just precomputing all neighbors within `K` from each node along with actual distance, and then doing a lookup based off that in descending order. Can't think of any smarter way of doing it at the moment.

Comment: You could pre-compute the graph with the Floyd-Warshall algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm